# changing the position and fontsize of the footline in beamer

Tags: beamer, header-footer, footnotes, fontsize

I created a slide template for a presentation in LaTex using Beamer package. I set a footline to be displayed with things like a logo and some text (a title and the name of university). At the moment in the following code, the footline text is very close to the border of the frame and I do not know how I can manipulate them and move it a bit higher with slightly bigger fontsize?!!

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,chains}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[frak=mma]{mathalfa}
%\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\newtcbox{\mymath}[1][]{%
    nobeforeafter, math upper, tcbox raise base,
    enhanced, colframe=yellow!30!black,
    colback=yellow!30, boxrule=1pt,
    #1}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black,bg=White!20}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[text line]{%
  \parbox{\linewidth}{\vspace*{10pt}\textcolor{gray}{ University of ..}\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{logo}\hfill\insertshortauthor\hfill\insertpagenumber}}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\author[\textcolor{gray}{Future of ...}]{\textcolor{blue}{Dr. John Smith}}
\title{\textbf{\textcolor{black}{Future of ...}\\\textcolor{gray}{Mathematical Foundations }}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

% Uncomment these lines for an automatically generated outline.
%\begin{frame}{Outline}
%  \tableofcontents
%\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\section{Convolution}
\end{document}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: There is *no* `\footnote` in your example!

Answer (score 1):

To move the footline up a bit, you could add vertical space after the template with `\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{}{\vskip0.5cm}`

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,chains}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[frak=mma]{mathalfa}
%\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\newtcbox{\mymath}[1][]{%
    nobeforeafter, math upper, tcbox raise base,
    enhanced, colframe=yellow!30!black,
    colback=yellow!30, boxrule=1pt,
    #1}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black,bg=White!20}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[text line]{%
  \parbox{\linewidth}{\scriptsize\vspace*{10pt}\textcolor{gray}{ University of ..}\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-duck}\hfill\insertshortauthor\hfill\insertpagenumber}
  }
  
\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{}{\vskip0.5cm}  
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\author[\textcolor{gray}{Future of ...}]{\textcolor{blue}{Dr. John Smith}}
\title{\textbf{\textcolor{black}{Future of ...}\\\textcolor{gray}{Mathematical Foundations }}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

% Uncomment these lines for an automatically generated outline.
%\begin{frame}{Outline}
%  \tableofcontents
%\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\section{Convolution}
\end{document}
```

[image]